# Why variable in $scope does not update?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Code in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hYWvg3XwRyIM12SHvyL2).
I have two controllers. In first controller i have handler for button in my view

```
 $scope.click = function () {
  $location.url("/some");
  console.log("clicked");
}
```

In handler i change URL. I also configured my $routeProvider.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []).config( function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/some', {template: " counter is {{n}}</br> <button ng-click='click()'>click to load new url but  still with \"loading cntl\"</button>", controller: "loading"})
  .when("/second",{controller: "loading"});
});
```

Here  i have two different routes that have the same controller - `loading` controller
So after my URL was changed to `/some` new button appears in my view. I have another handler for this button in `loading` controller.

```
app.controller("loading", function ($scope,$location) {
 $scope.n= $scope.n || 0;
 console.log("at the begining n is "+ $scope.n);
 $scope.click = function click() {
 $scope.n++;
 console.log("n after++ is " + $scope.n);
 $location.url("/second");
```

}

});
Here i increment `n` variable and change URL to `/second`. In my `$routeProvider` i indicated that route with this URL must have `loading controller` as well. After triggering of the button it disappears because `/second` router have no template. I press button on main view again, my `loading controller` is executed once more, but the `n` variable is still 0. Why the value of `n` is not `1`?
I know that my explanation is confusing, but i have the code in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hYWvg3XwRyIM12SHvyL2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're instantiating a new controller that has a new scope (and thus a new variable `n`). You need to keep the iteration data in something more persistant, like a parent scope, service, localStorage, etc (depends what you need the data for).

Here's a working example using `$rootScope`, just so you can see (you should probably use something other than the $rootScope in your final code): http://plnkr.co/edit/HETROBPwa6VyjX83Eev0?p=preview

I added a simple `console.log('scope', $scope);` in the controller, so you can see that each time you change the url, a new scope is created.

Comment: This is a good example - however I would recommend looking at a service instead of rootScope. Services are singletons and provide you the benefits of being easily testable and mocked.

Comment: @pherris Yeah, yeah, that's why I said OP should use something else in the final code - I did it with the rootscope because it was the quickest way to show him what's going on in the code.